# La anotacion @Transactional en mi clase DaoImp no se agrega como maven dependency. (SPRINGBOOT)

Tags: java, spring-boot

estoy creando una base de datos y estoy intentando conectarla con mi springboot donde tengo mis modulos, controladores, y mi DAO. Cree una clase en el DAO llamada UsuarioDaoImp y estoy intentando importar la anotacion @Transactional, entonces voy a intentar a agregarla como una maven dependency pero no me figura en el buscador de dependencias de maven. Intente actualizar las mavens dependencies y nada. Alguien sabe si ya esta obsoleto? Aca mi codigo de las dependencies en pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jonasrutishauser</groupId>
            <artifactId>transactional-event-liberty-it</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cursojava</groupId>
            <artifactId>curso</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con que gestor de base de datos vas a trabajar? debes poner en el pom el que has elegido